# Filter an object with choice filed values in django

Tags: django

I have following choice field in my model **Account**.

```
GENDER_CHOICES = (
    (1, 'Male'),
    (2, 'Female'),
    (3, 'Other'),
)
```

I want to search for a user on the basis of gender. How can I search/filter by either "male" or "female"?

Comment: can you share the model you are using this in ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can understand, if choices are:

```
GENDER_CHOICES = ( 
        (1, 'Male'), 
        (2, 'Female'), 
        (3, 'Other'), 
        )
```

Then you can use:

```
def your_view(request, gender):

    if gender == "male" or gender = "Male" :
        accounts = Account.objects.filter(gender=1)
    elif gender == "female" or gender = "Female":
        accounts = Account.objects.filter(gender=2)
    else :
        accounts = Account.objects.filter(gender=3)
```

As you mentioned in the comments,
If you have 20 choices:

```
def your_view(request, gender):

    id_list = [0,1,2,3 ....... 19]
    choice_list = ["choice 0","choice 1","choice 2","choice 3",....."choice 19"]

    for i in range(20):

        if gender == choice_list[i]:
            accounts = Account.objects.filter(gender=i)
```

Comment: Is it a good practice to use lower() on gender to avoid double check in if ?
`lower_gender = gender.lower()`
`if lower_gender == "male: [...]`

Comment: If the choice field contains 20 tuple data then i have to use this if  statement 20 times.Then what should i do at that time? Is there any generalized method to do this?

Comment: @TariqueSiddique In your question,you wrote **I want to search for a user on the basis of gender. How can I search/filter by either "male" or "female"?** How can this be 20 choices ??

Comment: @TariqueSiddique This is altogether new condition not mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that your model is called `Account` and that you have a `gender` field in it.

Since you are using numbers for your choices, you would do this:

```
male_accounts = Account.objects.filter(gender=1)
```

and you can get the rest using the same method.

**Edit:**

Since in your comment, you want to access them using

```
male_accounts = Account.objects.filter(gender='male')
```

you should change your `GENDER_CHOICES` to:

```
GENDER_CHOICES = (
    ('male', 'Male'),
    ('female', 'Female'),
    ('other', 'Other'),
)
```

quoting Django's official docs:

> The first element in each tuple is the actual value to be set on the model, and the second element is the human-readable name.
>   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#choices

Comment: But i want do the following way: male_accounts = Account.objects.filter(gender='male')